# Filtering models with ReferenceProperties

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using google app engine, and am having trouble writing querys to filter ReferenceProperties.

eg.

```
class Group(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    creator = db.ReferenceProperty(User)

class GroupMember(db.Model):
    group = db.ReferenceProperty(Group)
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
```

And I have tried writing something like this:

```
members = models.GroupMember.all().filter('group.name =', group_name)
```

and various other things that don't work. Hopefully someone can give me a prod in the right direction...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you want is to get the members of a group, ReferenceProperties have that built-in.

```
class GroupMember(db.Model):
    group = db.ReferenceProperty(Group, collection_name="groupMembers")
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name="groupMembers")
```

Then you can write:

```
# get the group entity somehow
group = Group.get(group_key)     
# do something with the members, such as list the nicknames
nicknames = [x.user.nickname for x in group.groupMembers]
```

Answer (score 5):

If your groups are uniquely named, then your "group.name" is a unique identifier of a Group entity.

That means you can write:

```
  members = models.GroupMember.all().filter(
    "group =",model.Group.gql("WHERE name=:1", group_name).get()
    )
```

though you only need to do that if you don't already have the group entity lying around in the stack somewhere.

Google's essay on many-to-many with appengine is [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html).

Answer (score 1):

This would require a join, which isn't possible in App Engine. If you want to filter by a property of another model, you need to include that property on the model you're querying against.

Answer (score 1):

This would result in two datastore hits but should work.  If you use memcache shouldnt be a problem.

```
group = models.Group.all().filter("name =", group_name).get()
members = models.GroupMember.all().filter('group =', group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Models that you defined in your question, lets say you want to list all members of a group called "*Space monkeys*".

```
mygroup = Group.gql("WHERE name = :1",'Space monkeys')

for group_member in mygroup.groupmember_set:
    print 'group members name is: %s' % (group_member.user.name)
```

The "`groupmember_set`" is called a "*implicit collection property*" and is very useful. You can call it whatever you want by over-riding the default name using the `collection_name` keyword parameter to `ReferenceProperty`. For an example see the answer by [Thomas L Holaday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448120/filtering-models-with-referenceproperties/539147#539147).

This is all explained in a very good paper by Rafe Kapla: [Modeling Entity Relationships](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html).